# MySQL Query count with multiple group per date/time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following data in `MySQL` table:

```
+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
|            DATE                     | SipResponseCode |
+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             500 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             487 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             500 |
| 20 Feb                              |             500 |
| 20 Feb                              |             487 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             500 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             200 |
| 20 Feb                              |             500 |
| 21 Feb                              |             200 |
| 21 Feb                              |             487 |
| 21 Feb                              |             200 |
| 21 Feb                              |             487 |
| 21 Feb                              |             487 |
| 21 Feb                              |             487 |
| 21 Feb                              |             487 |
| 21 Feb                              |             200 |
| 21 Feb                              |             200 |
| 21 Feb                              |             487 |
| 21 Feb                              |             487 |
| 21 Feb                              |             500 |
```

I want to write SQL query so it can give me count of SipResponseCode count per day `200`, `487`, `500`

```
+-------------------------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
|            DATE                     |    200     |    487    |   500  |
+-------------------------------------+------------+--------------------+
| 20 Feb                              |     14     |      2    |    5   |
| 21 Feb                              |     4      |      7    |    1   |
```

I have tired but cannot get correct results.

Comment: @Strawberry I am not `SQL expert` dude, come on! came here for help.. do i need to be expert to ask question?

Comment: Are the values 200, 487, and 500 consistent? Are those values you know ahead of time?

Comment: @McAdam331 yes those values are fix, there are few more SipResponsecode  `502`,`403`,`408` etc.. but once i know how to group them together i will manage to adjust them

Comment: @Strawberry I don't think that's the kind of attitude that helps StackOverflow. This should be a place that people look to for help when they need it, without fear of being belittled for not knowing something.

Comment: @Strawberry I am good at Linux system admin, but not developer (SQL writer), just got stuck here so thought you guys will help, but look like you `down` vote already... very disappointed :(

Comment: @McAdam331 My criticism is not at all directed at the OP's lack of knowledge. It's their lack of effort and the paucity of the question which I find disappointing. If we start talking about things I don't know we're going to be here a very, very long time.

Comment: @Strawberry there are many ways to write same query, and many will contribute to answer different way.  we are asking question to attract other folks here, who are new and seeking basic help. Everyone not born `Einstein` like you.

Comment: You miss my point. I'm criticising your lack of research and effort, not your lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values 200, 487, and 500 are constant values that you are aware of at the time of writing the query, you can use those in a case statement of your select clause.

Something a little more readable than a case statement is using the SUM() function with a condition, which will essentially count the number of rows that meet that condition. Try this:

```
SELECT dateColumn, 
   SUM(SisResponseCode = 200) AS '200', 
   SUM(SisResponseCode = 487) AS '487', 
   SUM(SisResponseCode = 500) AS '500'
FROM myTable
GROUP BY dateColumn;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you the results, not like you want per say, but in an easy way to parse it later in your language (PHP, C#, etc.).

```
SELECT  DATE, GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(TEST AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) SEPARATOR ",") AS myCol
FROM
(
    SELECT      DATE, CONCAT(SipResponseCode, "^",  COUNT(*)) AS TEST
    FROM        table1
    GROUP BY    DATE, SipResponseCode
) a
GROUP BY DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard answer would be roughly as follows:

```
SELECT date
     , sipresponsecode
     , COUNT(sipresponsecode) x 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY date
     , sipresponsecode;
```